# Data exchange with the daemon

Tags: go, daemon

There is daemon collecting messages from external source in local variable:

```
package main   
var externalData map[string]string

func main() {
   for {
    collectExternalData(&externalData)//Geting data from redis channel for example
   }
}
...
```

How can I get `externalData` by key from **another** synchronous script?

```
package main   

func getDaemonValueByKey() string {
//HOW TO DO IT?
}
...
```

Architecture can be flexible. Maybe it's possible to make all the functions inside of daemon module and subscribe to events? Now i can't imagine solution.

Comment: There are countless methods of IPC. Choosing one is not something we can do for you.

Comment: IPC is for one "root-process" routines in my opinion. In this case I need to communicate with another program.Or you mean that it is real to make 2in1: daemon and sync-handler?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I don't know what "root-process routines" means. IPC is any form of "Inter-Process Communication", since that's what it stands for. This could be a protocol over a pipe or network, or shared memory space, file-based communication, etc. There are infinite possibilities.